# convert angularjs this.$get to angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, provider

I'm converting a angularjs application to angular.

There is a provider in the application which posts to tumbler.

There is a this.$get function block which I'm not able to convert to angular.

I have created a service class in angular4 and i'm tying to implement this but i'm stuck on this **$get** and **.run** part .what is its use and how can the same be achieved in angular4.

The provider look like below:

```
angular.module('SoCXO.Advocate').
  provider('abc', [function () {


      var options = {};


      options.client_id = null;

      this.setClientId = function (clientId) {
          options.client_id = clientId;
          return this;
      };

      this.getClientId = function () {
          return options.client_id;
      };



      /**
       * This defines the Pin Service on run.
       */
      this.$get = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$http', function ($q, $rootScope, $timeout, $http) {

          /**
           * Define a deferred instance that will implement asynchronous calls
           * @type {Object}
           */
          var deferred;

          /**
           * NgPinInterest Class
           * @type {Class}
           */
          var NgTumbler = function () { };




          NgTumbler.prototype.handleClientLoad = function () {

          };

          NgTumbler.prototype.handleAuthResult = function (authResult) {


          };

          NgTumbler.prototype.postToTumbler = function (abkc) {
              deferred = $q.defer();

              hello('tumblr').login({ response_type: 'code' }).then(function (r) {

                /**Some Code Here**/


              }, function (e) {
                  deferred.resolve(false);
              });
              return deferred.promise;
          };


          return new NgTumbler();
      }];
  }]).run([function () {
  }

  ])
```

Comment: Does it need to be a provider? Maybe you can translate it into a service instead? The `$get` is almost the same as `return{}` in a service if I am not mistaken.